# How do I resolve the Zip code directive index issue?

Tags: angular

I am creating a zipcode directive that will get the additional counties if there are more than 1 so the user can select the correct one. I am currently erroring out in the for loop but I am not figuring this out as easy as I thought. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this or the proper fix to ensure this works.

code below:

```
//county
        if (dataArray[3]) {
          if (counties.length === 1 && dataArray.length > 3) {
            // debugger;
            this.control.controls[dataArray[3]].setValue(cities[0].county);
          }

          else if (counties.length >= 1) {
            // debugger;
            let optionText = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < counties.length; i++) {
              debugger;
              optionText += '<option index="' + i + '" value="' + counties[i].state + '|' + cities[i].county + '">' + cities[i].county + '</option>';
            }

            // debugger;
            const selectElement = '<div class="header"><h3 id="zip_div_title">Select County</h3><i id="county-picker-x" class="fal fa-times"></i></div><p class="select-city-label">Select the county from the list below</p><select id="select_county" size="3" class="county-popup">' + optionText + '</select>';
            const p: HTMLParagraphElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
            p.innerHTML = selectElement;
            p.classList.add('county-picker');
            this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.appendChild(p);

            const parentDiv: any = document.getElementsByClassName('county-picker')[0];
            const closeButton: any = document.getElementById('county-picker-x');
            const button: any = document.getElementById('select_county');
            button.focus();

            button.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
              const valueArray = button.value.split('|');
              const thisArray = this.array.split('|');
              this.control.controls[thisArray[3]].setValue(valueArray[1]);
              const element = document.getElementById(thisArray[3]);
              const thisevent = new Event('change');
              element.dispatchEvent(thisevent);

              if (typeof parentDiv.remove === 'function') {
                parentDiv.remove();
              } else {
                parentDiv.parentNode.removeChild(parentDiv);
              }
            });

            closeButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
              if (typeof parentDiv.remove === 'function') {
                parentDiv.remove();
              } else {
                parentDiv.parentNode.removeChild(parentDiv);
              }
            });
          }
        }
```